# In Databricks python notebook, how to import a file1 objects resides in different directory than the file2?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, databricks

Note: I did research on this over web but all of them are pointing to the solution which works on prem/desktops. This case is on databricks notebook, I referred databricks help guide but could not find the solution.

Dear all, 
In my local desktop i used to import the objects from other python files by referring their absolute path such as

"from dir.dira.dir0.file1 import *"

But in Databricks python notebook i'm finding it difficult to crack this step since 2 hours. Any help is appreciated.

Below is how my command shows,

from dbfs.Shared.ABC.models.NJ_WrkDir.test_schdl import *

also tried below ways, none of them worked

from dbfs/Shared/ABC/models/NJ_WrkDir/test_schdl import *

from \Shared\ABC\models\NJ_WrkDir\test_schdl import *

from Shared/ABC/models/NJ_WrkDir/test_schdl import *

from Shared.ABC.models.NJ_WrkDir.test_schdl import *

The error messages shows:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Shared

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbfs

SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
  File "", line 2
    from \Shared\ABC\models\NJ_WrkDir\test_schdl import *
                                                         ^

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, include the command in child databricks python notebook as

"%run /path/parentfile"

(from where we want to import the objects from)